# Conjugate of a domain

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I'm a university student just beginning to study complex numbers and our notes refer to the conjugate of a domain however I don't really understand what that means, is it just the set of values that are not contained in the domain?

Thanks

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the conjugate of the domain $D$ is$$\left\{\overline z\,\middle|\,z\in D\right\}.$$

Comment: So the conjugate of the domain is just the set of all the conjugates of D? Thanks very much!